# Adding rack controller to maas on ubuntu 20.04. throws "maas-rack: command not found" error

Tags: 20.04, maas

On an ubuntu 20.04. machine I have installed maas via

```
sudo snap install maas
```

and initiated it with the default configurations through

```
sudo maas init
```

As I only have a region controller, I selected "add a rack controller" in the dashboard/controllers, where I am told to install the maas-rack-controller package with the apt package manager and then do

```
sudo maas-rack register --url http://localhost:5240/MAAS --secret XXXXXXXXXX
```

However, I get error:

```
sudo: maas-rack: command not found
```

although the package has been properly installed.

Does anyone know what this could be due to ?

P.S.: This seems to work on bionic ...

Answer (score 0):

sudo maas init

Controller has already been initialized.
Are you sure you want to initialize again (yes/no) [default=no]? yes

Note: Configuring the MAAS snap in "all" mode will be
deprecated in MAAS 2.8.0 and removed in 2.9.0.

See https://maas.io/deprecations/MD1 for details.

Mode (all/region+rack/region/rack/none) [default=all]? rack
MAAS URL [default=http://192.168.1.8:5240/MAAS]: http://IPyours:5240/MAAS
Secret: Put the key  from http://IPyours:5240/MAAS/#/controllers    Add rack controller button

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a same issue. You need to use

```
 sudo maas init rack --maas-url $MAAS_URL --secret $SECRET
```

instead of running sudo maas-rack